# Using ng-include + ng-repeat so it isn't clunky

Tags: angularjs

We have some data like this:-

```
    fruits: [
        {
           type : "Apple",
           colour: "red"
        },
       {
          type: "Orange"
       }
    ]
```

To generate this, we have the following:-

```
<div ng-controller="FruitsController as fruitCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruitCtrl.fruits" ng-include="fruitCtrl.findInclude(fruit)" ng-init="fruit"></div>
</div>
```

fruitCtrl.findInclude is there to specify the location of the template. The template would be something like this:-

```
<div ng-contoller="AppleController as appleCtrl">
   {{ appleCtrl.data }}
</div>
```

The ng-init is there so we can pull through fruit in whatever controller is defined in the ng-include.

This looks very clumsy to me, especially in the controller, which ends up looking like this:-

```
 function AppleController($scope, colourService) {
        var vm = this;

        init();

        function init() {
              vm.data = colourService.convert($scope.fruit.colour);
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts on how to make this less clunky and clearer? Specifically, I cannot think of a way of avoiding the ng-init and the access to $scope in AppleController.  This makes it difficult to understand what is going on when looking at AppleController in isolation.

This example is presented in this plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/KitUvUnz52Ttl7fBVQxB?p=preview

**EDIT**
I had a coding error. I did not refrence $scope.fruit in AppleController.  This has been fixed.

Comment: I doubt you need the `ng-init` at all. You're not going to be able to avoid scope because you're using `ng-repeat`

Comment: You have gaps in the code that make the question confusing (at least to me). What is `fruitCtrl.data`? What is `findInclude`? `ng-init="fruit"` is completely useless here. Then you have `AppleController` - where is that used or coming from? And "less clunky" is *very* imprecise as the objective (epecially in absence of an alternative one)

Comment: Perhaps clunky means 'broken'?  I don't see this code even running, based on what has been provided.  Please provide relevant code...perhaps set up a plunker so we can have some clue as to what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I have fixed the examples given and provided a plunkr.

Comment: @user1545858, so this is working now? If so, I recommend that you delete this question

Comment: @NewDev Sorry, this is the question:- Any thoughts on how to make this less clunky and clearer?